# Como reducir la cantidad de un producto por lotes en C# y SQL SERVER?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Hola amigos estoy trabajando con windows-forms y sql-server, tengo lo siguiente: una tabla llamada tabla_items lo cual tiene campos (codigo, nombre, precio). Y otra tabla llamada tabla_lotes que contiene los campos (id_lote, codigo_item,cantidad, fecha_expiracion)

1. estos son los valores registrados en tabla_items:

| Codigo | Nombre | Precio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 675768555 | Leche | 50 |

2. estos son los valores registrados en tabla_lotes:

| ID_LOTE | CODIGO_ITEM | CANTIDAD | FECHA_EXPIRACION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 675768555 | 50 | 2021-10-20 |
| 2 | 675768555 | 20 | 2021-11-10 |
| 3 | 675768555 | 40 | 2021-10-15 |

Entonces tengo el producto "leche" con 3 distintas fechas de expiración y cada fecha de expiración tiene su cantidad respectiva.
mi objetivo es que al venderse el producto se reduzca primero del primer lote.
por decir vendo 25 leches, que se reduzca esos 25 del lote que contiene 50 leches.
y en caso que yo venda 60 leches reducir los 50 del primer lote y tomar los otros 10 leches del segundo lote.
alguien tiene alguna idea de como pudiera solucionar ?

**ESTO ES LO QUE HICE POR EL MOMENTO**

```
string sqlcantcad = "select cantidad, MIN(id_lote) from tbl_lotes where codigo_item = '675768555' and cantidad >'0' GROUP BY cantidad ";

DataAccess.ExecuteSQL(sqlcantcad);
DataTable dtCantidadCad = DataAccess.GetDataTable(sqlcantcad);

//AQUI RESTAMOS LA CANTIDAD VENDIDA DE LA CANTIDAD EXISTENTE        
int cantidad_producto_cad = Convert.ToInt32(dtCantidadCad.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString()) - cantidad_producto_vendido;

string id_lot = dtCantidadCad.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();

                    
//ACTUALIZAMOS LA CANTIDAD EN LA TABLA tabla_lotes  
string sqlcaducidad = "update tbl_lotes set " +
                                      " cantidad = '" + cantidad_producto_cad + "' " +
                                      " where codigo_item = '675768555' and id_lote ='"+id_lot+"'  ";
                            DataAccess.ExecuteSQL(sqlcaducidad);
```

Comment: Hay muchas maneras de solucionar este problema. Puedes crear tu propio **WMS** (Warehouse Management System), que te maneje el inventario. Puedes hacerlo con **procedimientos almacenados**. Puedes hacerlo con **TRIGGERS**. Puedes hacerlo desde C#. Cuál manera has intentado?

Comment: Aca obviamente no es un problema de winforms ni de c# ya que no dices nada de ellos...

Comment: @Arriel he editado la preguntado y adjuntado el codigo de loque hice por el momento. podrias ayudarme por favor.